# Java Stream Collectors sort the given stream

Tags: java-8, set, java-stream

can you please let me know why below code returns the set sorted order given an unsorted array?

```
    Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(2, 3, 1, 4, 5);

    Set<Integer> mySet = s.collect(Collectors.toSet());

    System.out.println(mySet);
```

O/p

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

This doesn't happen if I use List instead of Set.
Also the sorting is not always correct when there are negative numbers in the input.
Is there any inbuilt functionality to sort the Set?

Comment: *Also the sorting is not always correct* See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--]) *This is an unordered Collector.*

Answer (score 6):

This is just an accident and has nothing to do with `Collector` or `Stream`. On OpenJDK 11.0.2, I'm getting this (as `Collector.toSet()` is currently backed by `HashSet`):

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(2);
set.add(3);
set.add(1);
set.add(4);
set.add(5);
System.out.println(set); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But try this:

```
set.add(100);
System.out.println(set); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 5]
```

It is really just an accident. A very curious one, indeed, which has to do with the `Integer.hashCode()` implementation (it's just the `Integer.intValue()` itself), and how this results in accidentally ordering `HashSet` elements for certain sets.

Comment: `Set::of` is immune to this, at least if run enough times

Comment: You can also make the result more interesting by changing the construction to `new HashSet<>(4, 2f)`. Or you change the construction to `new HashSet<>(1, 5f)`, to start seeing the insertion order, apparently, but then, the `set.add(100)` destroys it…

Answer (score 1):

**It is just a coincidence**. The [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Set.html) interface does not provide any ordering guarantees, but [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).